# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\\Entities\\AccessToken

Tags: php, namespaces, facebook-php-sdk

I'm pretty new to the whole concept of name spaces!

I'm trying to use the Facebook API, The file set I'm using is facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev.

I've not changed the file structure.

My server is running PHP Verison 5.4.30

To start with I get the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\Entities\AccessToken

If I add this line the problem seems to solve the issue. But I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be doing that.

```
 require_once( 'Entities/AccessToken.php' );
```

Also I'm pretty sure this is a bad way of doing things. Does anyone have any idea why they aren't working?

Wondering if it's the version of PHP on the server?

```
 namespace Facebook;

 //require_once( 'Entities/AccessToken.php' );

 use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
 use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
```

Comment: You just need to autoload the classes, are you using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org)? If so, just ```require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'``` if not you'll need to setup your own autoloader or else require all the files you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using the Dev branch for the SDK instead of a stable release branch, like v4.0.9.

The Facebook SDK comes with an `autoload.php` class to help include all the files you need easily. Include then and then you can add the following lines:

```
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
```

Otherwise, you can manually include the classes as follows (assumes the Facebook PHP SDK files are in `./Facebook` folder):

```
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
```